# sid bootuping to vt1 terminal - Cannot open display "default display"

Tags: linux, boot, display, debian

Ones I wanted to make my computer boot to vt1 terminal, but I don't really record of doing so myself.

And so it happens than during boot it loads with tricks (I have log but haven't checked it).

It boots to vt1 terminal login:

```
Password:
Last login: Tue Feb 11 12:56:27 EET 2014 on tty2
Linux debian 3.12-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.12.9-1 (2014-02-01) x86_64
The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
No mail.
Cannot open display "default display"
06.2.052
12:57:47
carl@debian:~$
```

And I type `startx` & immediately `cat /dev/vcs1` afterwards:

```
best_post_div: 12
Set CRTC 0 PLL success
Set CRTC Timing success
Set CRTC 0 Overscan success
Not using RMX
scaler 0 setup success
Set CRTC 0 Source success
crtc 0 YUV disable setup success
Output UNIPHY2 transmitter setup success
Output DIG0 encoder setup success
Output DIG0 encoder setup success
Output UNIPHY2 transmitter setup success
Output UNIPHY2 transmitter setup success
Output UNIPHY2 transmitter setup success
Output UNIPHY2 transmitter setup success
Enable CRTC 0 success
Enable CRTC memreq 0 success
Unblank CRTC 0 success
Output CRT1 disable success
Output UNIPHY0 transmitter setup success
Blank CRTC 1 success
Disable CRTC memreq 1 success
Disable CRTC 1 success
Dac detection success
```

What I mean is - the hp dv7 laptop (5-year-old) started to act like this itself. I would really don't mind these conditions, but I would like to stop getting message in tenth line of login terminal:

Cannot open display "default display"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the way I install sid, afterwards it boots to vt1 (possible new debian policy, don't know that). Finally did a reinstall to find that out.

These two lines in `.bashrc` caused "cannot open display" message, so i just wraped it in `if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]` statement:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,lt" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
xset b off
```